# convert .skp file to .obj file without sketchup pro

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, .obj, sketchup

I want to convert .skp models to .obj in ubuntu 14.04. 
I have searched for any free version software for a good conversion.. but did not get any suitable answer and stuck here.

Any hint is most welcome...

Answer (score 1):

Try to export in format file .DAE, import on blender and export .obj.

Another possibility is search an extension on Sketchup(In some versions, the extension not works).

PS: this is the easiest and cheapest way I found.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFDQq2zVhuM http://sketchup2blender.com/blendup-get-started

Answer (score 0):

You may export to .DAE from SketchUp Make (the free version, for non-commercial purposes only) that runs on Wine (see `winetricks sketchup` for an auto-install!) and convert to .OBJ using the Assimp utils (e.g. `assimp export Untitled.dae Untitled.obj`).

[Babel3D](https://www.babel3d.com/) also provides a free plan for 3D format conversion, but I didn't test it.

Comment: The winetricks version of SketchUp can only read SKP files up to v8, unfortunately

Comment: It seems that [SketchUp works with Wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1815) up to [version 2016](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=33102).

Comment: @CrandellWS: How is there a licensing issue here? The answer you're linking to says the same: "Exporting as Collada .dae format from SketchUp works very well". This is limited to non-commercial uses if you use the free version, but it's the only limitation.